# How to access this in my services folder of NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello I learned NuxtJS in VueMastery and I think what they teach is really good. Where the pattern of getting data consists of async fetch, store and services.

**page/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$myInjectedFunction("works in mounted");
  },
  async fetch({ store, app, req, env }) {
    await store.dispatch("scooby/getBanners", { page: 1 });
  }
};
</script>
```

**store/scooby.js**

```
import ScoobyService from "@/services/ScoobyService.js";
export const state = () => ({
  banners: []
});
export const mutations = {
  SET_BANNERS(state, banners) {
    state.banners = banners;
  }
};
export const actions = {
  getBanners({ commit }, payload) {
    this.$myInjectedFunction("accessible in actions");
    const type = payload.type || 1;
    const params = `?ad_type=${type}&page=${payload.page}`;
    return ScoobyService.adBanner(params).then(response => {
      commit("SET_BANNERS", response.data);
    });
  }
};
```

**services/scoobyService.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { scoobyApiClient, scoobyRequestSetup } from "@/assets/js/axios.js";

const apiModule = "scooby";

const resources = {
  adBanner: `/v1/member/banners`
};

export default {
  adBanner(getParams) {
    // this.$myInjectedFunction("accessible in actions");
    const body = {};
    const resource = `${resources.adBanner}/${getParams}`;
    const [api, req] = scoobyRequestSetup(resource, body, apiModule);

    return process.server
      ? scoobyApiClient.get(api, req)
      : scoobyApiClient.post(api, req);
  }
};
```

**plugins/combined-inject.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject("myInjectedFunction", string => console.log("That was easy!", string));
};
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
    plugins: [
    "~/plugins/axios.js"
  ],
  ...
}
```

The **services/scoobyService.js** can not access the `this` object but **store/scooby.js** can. How can I access the this object in **services/scoobyService.js**

Comment: You can't access `this` directly, why do you want to access ?

Comment: I plan to use plugins/axios.js then inside `plugins/axios.js` I will inject an axios.create so I can use `this.$scoobyApiClient`.

One of the other reasons is so I can put the Client IP in the headers of my axios instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your files as below, then you can access your service methods with `this.$customService`

**services/CustomService.js**

```
export default {
  hello() {
    return 'Hello'
  },
  bye() {
    return 'Bye'
  }
}
```

**plugins/combined-inject.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ServiceOnefrom '../services/ServiceOne'
Vue.prototype.$ServiceOne= ServiceOne

// or

// import ServiceOne from '../services/ServiceOne'
// export default ({ app }, inject) => {
//  inject("serviceOne", ServiceOne);
// };
```

Comment: I meant accessing `this` inside my service

Comment: If so you can create your service as plugin, then you can access Vue instance with `export default ({ app }) => {...}`

Comment: Is there any other way besides NuxtJS plugin? I will have many service maybe even 20.. So it will be troublesome if I will add all of those as plugins

Comment: There won't be any trouble, you can use thousands of service, the only thing you have to do is exporting your service functions inside plugin file

Comment: Sorry I got to admin but I'm a beginner.. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada Created a live session on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/live/KGArn

Comment: I am currently checking

Answer (score 1):

Your injected function will only be available in valid Vue instances, which your scoobyService.js isn't (see: [**Vue instance properties**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html)). You could expose the function separately as an export as well and use it that way in your services.

```
export const myInjectedFunction = string => console.log("That was easy!", string);
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject("myInjectedFunction", myInjectedFunction );
};
```

Then import that function separately whenever your want to use it outside of Vue instances

Comment: I am using services the wrong way? Or is services not really a good pattern in NuxtJS?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada There is nothing stopping you from using service oriented architecture in your NuxtJS project, just realize that these services exists outside of your Vue context so Vue instance methods your create will not be accessible in your services (`this` in your service does not refer to a valid Vue instance). That's why i suggested you just export your function separately and import it in your service. Hope that clears it up

Comment: Is there a way to put these services inside the Vue context?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada in my code, I already created example for it... Import your service then export it or create a prototype with it using Vue instance

Comment: Sorry but all I see is a const variable and inject in your code

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada that's a different commentor, he's talking about his own answer.

Comment: @etarhan Oh sorry.